# Printing out a non-variable int in a different method in Java

Tags: java, string, variables

I am trying to test whether my method to find the number of odd numbers in an array works with a `System.out.println()` call. I know there are no issues with the array itself, as I've printed it successfully with the toString() call. Here is my method:

```
public static int ODD(int[] oddnumbers)
{
    int countOdds = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < oddnumbers.length; i++)
    {
    if(oddnumbers[i] % 2 == 1) // check if it's odd
          countOdds++;        // keep counting
      }
      return countOdds;

}
```

And then earlier on in the main method, I called ODD and tested it with System.out.println:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    ODD(randomThirty);  // will find how may numbers in the given numbers (from the array) are ODD numbers and return this count to main method.
    System.out.println("And here are how many odd numbers there are in that array: " + countOdds);
```

}

Basically the question I have is, how do I get the `return countOdds` into a variable that I can pass to be printed in System.out.println() in the `main` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a temporary variable to store the returned value and print that, or include the method call in the print statement. For more information, see [Returning a Value from a Method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

`System.out.println("And here are how many odd numbers there are in that array: " + ODD(randomThirty));`

Comment: Thank you Saket, that makes sense that I am just putting in whatever returned from the ODD method. I'll remember this for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `int countOdds = ODD(randomThirty);` in your main method.

Your `countOdds` variable in your function is local to that function. Variables defined in functions in java are local not global.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the result of the `ODD` method call to a variable:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int result = ODD(randomThirty);  // will find how may numbers in the given numbers (from the array) are ODD numbers and return this count to main method.
    System.out.println("And here are how many odd numbers there are in that array: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the return result of your call to `ODD` in a variable, like so:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int countOdds = ODD(randomThirty);  // will find how may numbers in the given numbers (from the array) are ODD numbers and return this count to main method.
    System.out.println("And here are how many odd numbers there are in that array: " + countOdds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the result like any other variable:

```
int countOdds = ODD(randomThirty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int countOdds = ODD(randomThirty);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the returned value you have to pass the argument into the method and call it.

```
    int ans = ODD(randomThirty); 
    System.out.println(ans);
```

This is really all you need to do. You can call methods while passing an argument and assign a variable to the returned answer.